# How to convert x509 Cert and Key to a pkcs12 file

Tags: java, bouncycastle, x509

To convert a pem file containing a x509 certificate + private key into a pkcs12 (.p12) file, the following command is being used:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey cert_pkey.pem -in cert_pkey.pem -out cert.p12
```

I am trying to accomplish the same programatically using Java with BouncyCastle library. I am able to extract the X509Cert from the PEMObject but the Private key has been confusing.

Any help in piecing together the steps is appreciated:

1. Open cert_pkey.pem file stream using PEMParser
2. Get the X509 Certificate from PemObject (done)
3. **Get the private key from the PemObject (how?)**
4. Create KeyStore of instance type PKCS12 with password

Comment: Got any code? So you're stuck on step 3?

Comment: @weston posted the solution that worked out for me below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got around how to get the cert and key separately - not sure why it worked out the way it worked out:

```
PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(certStream)));
Object pemCertObj = pemParser.readObject();
PemObject pemKeyObj = pemParser.readPemObject();

PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pemKeyObj.getContent());
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey privKey = kf.generatePrivate(privKeySpec);

Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
X509CertificateHolder certHolder = (X509CertificateHolder)pemCertObj;
X509Certificate x509cert = (new JcaX509CertificateConverter()).setProvider("BC").getCertificate(certHolder);
```

I got the hint when I looked up the `.getType()` on `permCertObj` and `permKeyObj` and got `RSA CERT` and `RSA PRIVATE KEY` respectively returned.

Couldn't figure out the difference between `readObject()` and `readPemObject()`

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: scala, i am using it as part of Play app.

Comment: Then why have you tagged the question as java not scala?

Comment: since the library is in Java and any example in Java is what I expected for a Java lib.

Comment: Exactly, I would also expect a java answer.

Comment: I can edit to add Java answer. If you are the one downvoting the question/answer based on that - just ask and I can change it. Thanks!

Comment: Suggest you can either change the tag to scala or the answer to Java, or both add scala tag and a Java answer.

Answer (score 0):

The PEMParser class will parse just about anything from PEM format. You can read the object from the file using that parser - if you'll print the class of that object you'l;l see it's a PEMKeyPair. That can be converted to a regular KeyPair using JcaPEMKeyConverter.

```
public KeyPair importKeyFromPemFile(String filePath)
{
    try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath))
    {
        PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(reader);
        PEMKeyPair pemKeyPair = (PEMKeyPair)pemParser.readObject()
        return new JcaPEMKeyConverter().getKeyPair(pemKeyPair);
    }
    catch (IOException | PEMException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: The pemObject is throwing an error when I cast it to PEMKeyPair, since the pem file only has the private key + cert and no public key.

I had to create a private key object from the PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pemParser.readPemObject().getContent)